# Retrieve customer order product ID Shopify

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-template

I have created a page which will be accessible only if they purchase this certain product. My problem is I am not sure how to retrieve the customer Order product list ID.

for example customer A, purchased product A & B,
then customer A would be able to access page A & B

I tried this but it what it retrieves is the order ID's not the product ID's of the orders made by the customer

```
{% for order in customer.orders %}
{{ order.id }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order object in Shopify contains information about purchased products in `line_item`. You should do something like this:

```
{% for order in customer.orders %}
  {% for line_item in order.line_items%}
     {{ line_item.product_id }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

You can find information about line_item object in the official documentation: https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/objects/line_item